# Java throws java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException, but file exists

Tags: java, spring, docker, file, spring-rest

I'm running a Spring REST application inside a docker container. I have a function inside a Spring controller for saving images and a function for reading them. The function for saving works properly but I have an issue with the function for reading them:

```
public byte[] getByteArray(String fileName) {
    try {
        File f  = new File("/upload/" + fileName);
        return Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // this is for testing
        return null;
    }
}
```

However after I use the above function I get this error `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /upload/test.png`. I checked and this file exists in this directory. What could be the reason Java can't see this file?

Comment: Well, the first debugging step would be to print the absolute path of the `f` to see if it matches your expectations (e.g. using [`f.getAbsolutePath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath())).

Comment: @Hulk the absolute path is the same as in the exception: `/upload/test.png`.

Comment: Ok. Try to list the files your application can see - start at the root dir `/`, and see if it can see `/upload`, check that it recognizes `/upload` as a directory... if not, check file permissions.

Comment: Where did you place the folder ?

Comment: @AnishB. in the root directory.

Comment: I tried the same code. it's working on my system.

Comment: Did you check whether saving is happening or not ?

Comment: The saving works and I'm using the same path as here.

Comment: Is your app deployed on the docker ?

Comment: @AnishB. yes it runs on docker on Windows (uses WSL 2)

Comment: Can you run the app without docker and check the functionality whether it's working or not?

Comment: Which root directory; does the `/upload` directory exist inside the container?  Can you show your image's Dockerfile, especially where it creates the directory and sets up its permissions?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes it exists, I even entered the container and changed the permissions for both the directory and file to 777, but it still won't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `/upload` directory is not accessible to the java process. directories have access rights, an owner, and a group. There is one set of rights for the owner, one for the group, and one for the rest.

Comment: The same thing happens when I place the file in the root directory.

Comment: Then it's definitely an access rights issue. That or there is a character in your `fileName` string that looks like a `t` but isn't a `t` - the unicode table is littered with em; check each unicode code point to eliminate that option. On a mac, by any chance? Macs deny all file access blanket style, and show a popup instead. If you clicked 'deny' on that, this happens. Go into your security settings and play around inside there.

Comment: it seems that it was something related to encoding. I didn't check specifically, but changing the filename helped.